# C# generic types at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, types

I'm trying to dynamically generate reports and email them to the appropriate users is this possible or can does the compiler need the type before runtime.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    ArrayList ReportsTypes = new ArrayList();
    ReportsTypes.Add(typeof(AgentPPL));
    foreach(Type t in ReportsTypes) {
        InitilizeReports<t>(); // <- Error
    }
}
static void InitilizeReports<T>() where T : new() {
    T r = new T();
    IReportDocument rd = (IReportDocument)r;
    rd.DocumentName = "SomeReport";
    ExportReport(rd);
}
```

What I'd really like to do is grab a string out of the database and convert the string to a type but I doubt thats possible but what about creating an array of types like in my example what am doing wrong here.  Any help is much appreciated I've been spinning my wheels for a while just to get my templates working.

Comment: It seems you already know the type to some degree:
`IReportDocument rd = (IReportDocument)r;`.  You should declare `T` also implements `IReportDocument`, add that to the `where` clause.  Is `ExportReport` overloaded to operated on specific types?

Comment: Well you can find the type from the name which returns the actual type, and then use reflection to new it up and invoke members. It's really pretty and as far as I know, reflection isn't exactly the fastest way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the code just a bit and use reflection instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ArrayList ReportsTypes = new ArrayList();
    ReportsTypes.Add(typeof(AgentPPL));


    foreach (Type t in ReportsTypes)
    {
        InitilizeReports(t);
    }


}

static void InitilizeReports(Type t)
{
    var r = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    AgentPPL rr = new AgentPPL();
    IReportDocument rd = (IReportDocument)r;
    rd.DocumentName = "SomeReport";
    ExportReport(rd);
}
```

Comment: @Matt: hmm...this solution creates an AgentPPL instance twice and for any other type too

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following approaches:

```
ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator();
// 1. Invoke method with single parameter
foreach(Type t in ReportsTypes) {
    generator.InitilizeReportsByType(t);
}
// 2. Make and invoke generic method without parameter via reflection
MethodInfo mInfo = typeof(ReportGenerator).GetMethod("InitilizeReportsGeneric");
foreach(Type t in ReportsTypes) {
    MethodInfo genericMethod = mInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { t });
    genericMethod.Invoke(generator, new object[] { });
}


public class ReportGenerator {
    public void InitilizeReportsByType(Type type) {
        IReportDocument reportDocument = (IReportDocument)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        //...
    }
    public void InitilizeReportsGeneric<T>() where T : IReportDocument, new() {
        T reportDocument = new T();
        //...
    }
}
```

Note, that `T reportDocument = new T()` are equal to `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` because it is only compiler syntax sugar.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to a Type with **[Type.GetType(string typeName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)**:

```
Type intType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```

Comment: Oh sweet this is what I been looking for too.  Thanks to everyone that replied

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of a class from a string as follows:

```
Type reportType = Type.GetType("ClassName.Including.Namespace");
IReportDocument report = (IReportDocument)Activator.CreateInstance(reportType);
```